# How to move to particular Widget lower down on the screen upon a button press on a Flutter App?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a scroll-able page that has a button on the top. I would like the page view to move to a widget that is situated lower down when that button is pressed. Could someone explain using a sample piece of code to do this.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and where you failed. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ScrollController.animateTo`([refer](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html)) to scroll to specific scroll position(not to specific widget as far as I know). We have to attach ScrollController to your Scrollable view.

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52139903/5305962) for scrolling code. It's auto scroll, but it might help you.